# Doing calculations in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a collection of a custom type which I have plugged into a datagrid. The datagrid displays various properties of the type, but I want to include in the datagrid some "on the fly" columns which are calculations of other columns.

So for example, here is my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Margin="5, 15" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding StandardTrades}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStandardTrade}" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 20 8 8" materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Binding="{Binding TradeDate, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Header="Trade Date" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Client" Binding="{Binding Exchange.Client.Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Clearer" Binding="{Binding Exchange.Clearer.Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Exchange" Binding="{Binding Exchange.ExchangeCode}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="CCY" Binding="{Binding Exchange.Currency.Code}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="B/S" Binding="{Binding BOrS}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Product" Binding="{Binding Product}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Volume" Binding="{Binding Volume}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Maturity" Binding="{Binding Maturity}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Reference" Binding="{Binding Reference}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Rate" Binding="{Binding Exchange.Rate}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Commission total" Binding="{Binding Exchange.Rate * Exchange.Volume}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, on the last column, I want to produce an output which calculates the Rate * Volume.

How would I go about doing this? I'm not sure how to use convertors before so if I need to use this can someone show me how, please?

Many thanks

Comment: Google something like "multibinding converter wpf".  Here is the [top result](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-Multi-binding-and-Multi-value-Conv) which should get you started

Comment: Thank you for this Greg, I posted my solution thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to Greg for showing me multibinding converters, I've not come across them till today.

This is how I came to a solution.

I created a new converter class:

```
public class AddConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        decimal result = int.Parse(values[0].ToString()) * decimal.Parse(values[1].ToString());
        return result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The Convert method takes in the first param as an int and the second param as a decimal in order to calculate the total commission.

I then plugged this into my XAML code, ensuring first that I include the converter as a resource to my class:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:AddConverter x:Key="AddConvertor"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then finally implementing this in the datagrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true" Header="Commission total">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AddConvertor}">
            <Binding Path="Volume" />
            <Binding Path="Exchange.Rate" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```